# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, frontend

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

вот код

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  document.getElementsByClassName("slide").style.backgroundImage =
    "url(../img/slide2.jpg)"
}, 5000);
```

в чем проблема и как поправить?

Comment: Почитайте документацию по getElementsByClassName

Comment: используйте jquery :) $(".slide").css({" background ":" url(img.jpg) "})  Или  getElementById()

Comment: То есть к стилям классам стандартными  средствами js ,не обратится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `document.getElementsByClassName()` [возвращает массивоподобный (итерируемый) объект всех дочерних элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) .

Можно делать следующим образом

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0].style.backgroundImage =
    "url(../img/slide2.jpg)"
}, 5000);
```

если элемент с таким классом на странице один, либо перебирать все элементы массива и для применять для каждого из них.